# What does Linux wait for when switches from Xorg to text console?

Tags: xorg, linux-kernel, console, graphics, deadlock

Sometimes my Xorg hangs and locks the console dead, with a “stale frame” of GUI on the monitor. Hardware and driver-related problems are likely (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663414/nouveau-kernel-faults-and-xorg-sometimes-stucks-or-is-it-hardware-at-fault) for description of particular configuration), but this question is focused on a particularly annoying effect: inability to switch to text mode. Otherwise the system is fully functioning. The box serves a LAN, I can log in and even run somethings like `chvt` inside, to no avail. Of course, I can terminate the Xorg process to free the console… but it’s so rude. Not the same situation as in [that question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123048/switching-from-xorg-to-console-does-not-work), where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> failed consistently, but, in my case, it fails *sometimes* and only when X is unable to work anyway.

So, the question: **Which exactly step of console switching is vulnerable to deadlocks?** Modern Linux kernels (3.x) are assumed. Many years ago (in the age of Linux 2.4) I had reasonably good understanding of virtual console-related stuff and even wrote some notes about it, but modern `vc_screen.c` changed considerably from 10-years-old specimens, with such new calls as `console_lock()` and `console_unlock()` appeared in it.

Comment: Related (loosely): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-to-find-blockage-for-virtual-terminal-switching