# How to find blockage for Virtual Terminal switching?

Tags: console

I am stuck on virtual terminal 14. Starting some SDL-software brought me there. Now I cannot go anywhere else. Every "chvt" freezes (at the "VT_WAITACTIVE" ioctl) if it is not chvt 14 which succeeds. There is no chvt running. I can start shell and Xorg on vt14 (from remote ssh).

How to be able to switch vt again (other than rebooting)? How to kill any maybe pending and thus blocking vt switch? looking at the output of ps -A did not reveal any suspicious process (except maybe Xorg, killing it is not an option). Any getty I already killed (and they got restarted by init).

Graphics: uvesafb, Xorg uses fbdev, no kernel mode setting, sysvinit/openrc (no systemd).

Comment: Is it still a problem? Can you find with `lsof` which processes have `/dev/tty14` open?

Comment: @ Incnis Mrsi: I tried lsof | grep tty14 and fuser /dev/tty14, no result. Now it is not a problem anymore since I just rebooted the system (I was not able to get to my runnung old X session on vt13, x11vnc does not work on the very same machine due to Xorg not updating if it's vt is not active), but it might happen again, although very seldom.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it applies to your case, but I saw these symptoms when virtual terminal switching was turned off with `physlock -l`. Running `physlock -L` unlocked switching, both from the keyboard and with `chvt`.

Comment: Interesting, I even did not know about `physlock` and I don't had/ have it installed.

Comment: I've seen X get stuck pretty hard - almost always due to some game doing something or other that was doubtless unnecessary - where chvt and the like will only work most of the time, but occasionally would get wedged so hard chvt would block (until it interrupted itself) in the VT_ACTIVATE call (and then loop), and IN THAT CASE - even phylock -L doesn't help (at least in my small test sample).

Comment: That sounds like you might be running into GPU driver bugs. You can check the kernel-side stack trace of blocked tasks to confirm.